# How does c language store int in memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, byte, bit

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *p_x = (int *)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d", p_x);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        char *one_byte_slice = (((char *)(p_x)) + i);
        printf("slice : %d , value : %d\n", i, *one_byte_slice);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I entered positive values they seems understandable to me but for negative I don't understand it well.

For `*p_x = 127`:

```
127
slice : 0 , value : 127
slice : 1 , value : 0
slice : 2 , value : 0
slice : 3 , value : 0

p_x  --->  0111 1111
           0000 0000
           0000 0000
           0000 0000
```

For `*p_x = 256`:

```
256
slice : 0 , value : 0
slice : 1 , value : 1
slice : 2 , value : 0
slice : 3 , value : 0

p_x  --->  0000 0000
           0000 0001
           0000 0000
           0000 0000
```

For `*p_x = -20`:

```
-20
slice : 0 , value : -20
slice : 1 , value : -1
slice : 2 , value : -1
slice : 3 , value : -1

p_x  --->  1001 0100
           1000 0001
           1000 0001
           1000 0001
```

And for `*p_x = -256`:

```
-256
slice : 0 , value : 0
slice : 1 , value : -1
slice : 2 , value : -1
slice : 3 , value : -1

p_x  --->  0000 0000
           1000 0001
           1000 0001
           1000 0001
```

So how is it stored in memory for fixed point numbers is is stored in 2's complement or other way?

Comment: maybe better ==> `unsigned char *one_byte_slice = ( ((unsigned char *)(p_x)) + i);` and use `"%u"` in `printf()` *format string*.

Comment: Using `printf` with `%d` won't show you the raw bits of the byte slice, btw. Use `%u` instead, or use bitshifting to see the bits yourself.

Comment: You are trying to understand how negative values are represented in memory, but you are doing it by printing negative values for the bytes. To see the representations in memory, you should be printing the individual bits, or at least hexadecimal from which it is easy to see the bytes. First, use `unsigned char`, not `char`, since `char` may be signed. Second, for each byte, print it in hexadecimal, using `%hhx`. Better yet would be to print it in binary, but, to do that, you have to write your own code to print the individual bits, because there is not a standard `printf` conversion for that.

Comment: To start, work with a single `unsigned char`. Print its value in hexadecimal after it is assigned the values 0, 1, 2, 3, then, −1, −2, −3. When you think you understand how the bits of a single byte represent values, then look at the bytes of an `int`. (Technically, assigning values such as −1 to an `unsigned char` shows you the result of a conversion by value rather than the actual representation used for a `signed char`. However, in typical modern C implementations, those have the same result.)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called low-endian encoding.  The individual bit slices of the integer are stored from least significative to most significative in the consecutive byte cells.
Your integer is represented in binary form as:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1111
```

(where I have used a space to separate each group of four bits).
Each byte is stored from the least significant group of eight bits to the most, in growing byte addresses, starting from the right above:

```
Addr.  Value.
0000: 0111 1111
0001: 0000 0000
0002: 0000 0000
0003: 0000 0000
```

There's another way to do it, which is called big-endian, which stores the bytes just in the reverse direction, and some machines do it:

```
(Big-endian)
Addr.  Value.
0000: 0000 0000
0001: 0000 0000
0002: 0000 0000
0003: 0111 1111
```

There are other ways to do, but today's computers normally use one  of these two.

In the case of negative numbers, the solution consists in thinking that negative numbers and positive numbers are so that adding and subtrating can be done withou having to use an alternate circuitry.  So numbers are divided in two halves and the ones with the most significant bit represent the negative ones... so numbers are represented (I'll use only four bits for brevity):

```
1000: -8
1001: -7
1010: -6
1011: -5
1100: -4
1101: -3
1110: -2
1111: -1
0000: 0
0001: 1
0010: 2
0011: 3
0100: 4
0101: 5
0110: 6
0111: 7
```

With 32 bits the result is the same, but extended to 32 bits... this makes that all the small negative numbers have all the most significant bits equal to `1`.

```
1000 0000 0000 0000: -2147483648
1000 0000 0000 0001: -2147483647
...
1111 1111 1111 1101: -3
1111 1111 1111 1110: -2
1111 1111 1111 1111: -1
0000 0000 0000 0000: 0
0000 0000 0000 0001: 1
...
0111 1111 1111 1100: 2147483644
0111 1111 1111 1101: 2147483645
0111 1111 1111 1110: 2147483646
0111 1111 1111 1111: 2147483647
```

in such a way that adding is jumping in the previous table downwards and subtracting going upwards.  This is called *two's complement* encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i think i got my answer.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *p_x = (int *) malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d",p_x);

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        unsigned char *one_byte_slice = ( ((unsigned char *)(p_x)) + i);
        printf("slice : %d , value : %hhx\n",i,*one_byte_slice);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When i tried `%hhx` and `unsigned char *` it's shows me `2's` complement for negative values.

```
-1
slice : 0 , value : ff
slice : 1 , value : ff
slice : 2 , value : ff
slice : 3 , value : ff


p_x  --->  1111 1111
           1111 1111
           1111 1111
           1111 1111
```

```
-3
slice : 0 , value : fd
slice : 1 , value : ff
slice : 2 , value : ff
slice : 3 , value : ff

p_x  --->  1111 1101
           1111 1111
           1111 1111
           1111 1111
```

Yeah so conclusion is it's stored in `2's` complement format.

Comment: This is a correct conclusion, *for the machine you're using today*.  But this is a property of your machine, not of the C language.  Indeed the vast majority of machines today are two's complement, but the C language allows for the possibility of one's complement or sign/magnitude representations also.

Comment: @SteveSummit: It is a property of the C implementation, not the machine. For example, C implementations are sometimes written to enable running old software on new hardware, and such an implementation would adopt whatever `int` size and representation the old software was designed for even if that means the compiler has to generate extra instructions to implement it on the current hardware.